# Angular: <ol> added by document.execCommand sees only css rules in styles.css but not in the component's css

Tags: html, css, angular, html-lists, execcommand

I am creating rich text editor in angular and when I execute `document.execCommand('insertOrderedList')` I get `<ol>` item which is unaffected by my component's css, only css in `styles.css` (main css file in the root of the project) affects items I am adding with `document.execCommand`.
Is it possible to change this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. The name for it is [view encapsulation](https://angular.io/guide/view-encapsulation). Changing it to `ViewEncapsulation.none` would make the desired behavior.

```js
@Component({
  ...
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.none
})
```

Comment: Is it possible to do it without making the whole .css from my component global? I am adding <ol> to the component which has all css rules I need but for some reason these rules don't work, only global rules (in style.css) work. This applies only to elements added by `document.execCommand`, if I manullay add tags in the .html file it is being styled properly with component's css rules

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand

Comment: `execCommand` is deprecated. better to avoid it

Comment: `insertOrderedList` seems to be a function which add the `ol` tag. I bet it is possible (and way better) to use Angular capabilities instead of manually change the DOM

Comment: sorry, I understand it might be disappointing. in a long run leveraging Angular capabilities would pay off for sure. it worth to learn it and use it

Comment: I don't know how I didn't notice this big red warning at first but thanks for pointing this out. I am using execComand because it is almost perfect for my use case to let users style  the text they are inputing. I will follow your advice and manipulate DOM using angular or other api instead. Thanks